# Angular : Unable to upload file on web API using HttpPostedFileBase

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api, angular-cli, angular-file-upload

I want to upload a file on form submit, but its not posting on web API.

And save file in a local physical path using Web API.

Here I am trying to send file using FormData and trying to access the same in api call using HttpPostedFileBase but its posting on given url(no error).

**Html :**

```
<form [formGroup]="employeeForm" (ngSubmit)="save()" #formDir="ngForm" novalidate style="position:relative;" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div>
 <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="Name">
        <input type="file" id="FileUploader" (change)="onFileChange($event)" #fileInput accept=".pdf,.doc,.docx,.png">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" (click)="clearFile()">clear file</button>
      </div>
</form>
```

**Component :**

```
myFiles: string[] = [];
  form: FormGroup;
  loading: boolean = false;
  @ViewChild('fileInput') fileInput: ElementRef;

onFileChange(e) {        
  for (var i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) {
    this.myFiles.push(e.target.files[i]);
   } 
  }
save() {
   const frmData = new FormData();
   let fileBrowser = this.fileInput.nativeElement;
   frmData.append("myFile", fileBrowser.files[0]);

      this._employeeService.saveEmployee(this.employeeForm.value, frmData)
        .subscribe((data) => {
          this._router.navigate(['/fetch-employee']);
        }, error => this.errorMessage = error)
    }
```

**Service :**

```
saveEmployee(employee, myFile): Observable<any> {
   return this._http.post(this.myAppUrl + 'api/Employee/Create', { employee: employee, myFile: myFile }, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': undefined,
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  }
 });
 }
```

**Web API :**

```
  public int Create([FromBody] TblEmployee employee, HttpPostedFileBase myFile)
            {
             //code    
            }
     public partial class TblEmployee
        {
            public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }              
        }
```

Comment: What is the response received in network tab?

Answer (score 1):

Do not add `Content-Type` header. Let the browser detect the `Content-Type` and add by itself.

So comment out it in your code

```
saveEmployee(employee, myFile): Observable<any> {
   return this._http.post(this.myAppUrl + 'api/Employee/Create', { employee: employee, myFile: myFile }, {
    headers: {
    //'Content-Type': undefined,
    'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Now, its returing POST http://localhost:35257/api/Employee/Create 500 (Internal Server Error)..

Comment: What was the response returned earlier?

Comment: i also tried these 2 but none of them is working for me, my api is on a different project  bdw, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51021454/angular-unable-to-upload-file-using-web-api and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51016370/how-to-upload-a-file-on-form-submit-using-web-api-and-angular

Comment: Seems like an issue with your api. Did you try testing from the postman or any other tools?

Comment: One Advise : Before asking any question make sure that you research properly and let us know what is working and what is not. If you are not sure yourself, it is difficult to solve.

Comment: i was not aware of how to post from postman with a file, thats why i didn't check yet..

Answer (score 0):

You should put all your data insite `FormData`

```
const frmData = new FormData();
let fileBrowser = this.fileInput.nativeElement;
frmData.append("myFile", fileBrowser.files[0]);
frmData.append("employee", employee);
```

And the in API you should use `IFormFile`

```
public IActionResult Create(string employee, IFormFile myFile)
```

---

**Update**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.1

```
public class TblEmployee 
{
    // your employee info

    public IFormFile MyFile{ get; set; }
}
```

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
```

Comment: how to use this IFormFile ? or it should be formcollection?

Comment: You can one by one append data from all properties in `employee` object to `FormData` and then send to server

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Comment: its really difficult to upload a file on angular with other form properties????????